# make the text take up as much space as the picture in grid with

Tags: html, css

i'm working on a school project where im supposed to do a portfolio. im trying to make a grid with pictuers and information next to that picture about stuff i have worked on. I'm trying to get the textbox to be as big as the picture. I have tried jusing flexbox and a lot of other stuff but can't get it to work. is there someone who can help me?

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}


.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  margin:8px-16px; 
}

.row,
.row > .column {
  padding:2px 0px;
}

.column {
  float:left;
  width:50%;  
}

.row:after {
  content:"";
  display:table;
  clear:both;
}

.content {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 10px;   
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .column {
    width:100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Hemsida 1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>   
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="atleta1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="atleta1.jpg" style="width:100%">´
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Hemsida 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <h3>Hemsida 2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="column">
      <div class="content">
        <img src="atleta1.jpg" style="width:100%">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have complicated the layout very much. How do you like this layout option?

Each line is divided into two parts of 50%.

**A small bonus**: with small screens, due to the Flexbox property `order`, the description block is located above the picture.

P.S. Of course, this is not the final option. You can continue to improve it

### Result

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  ;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.item__desc {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.item__pic {
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

.item_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .item {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .item__desc {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item__desc">
      <h3>Hemsida 1</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item__pic">
      <img class="item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item__pic">
      <img class="item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354">
    </div>
    <div class="item__desc">
      <h3>Hemsida 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li class="item">
    <div class="item__desc">
      <h3>Hemsida 2</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item__pic">
      <img class="item_img" src="https://picsum.photos/536/354"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And same code on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/wvwNRxQ?editors=1100)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

will be enough for homework. Edit and improve codes

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.box{
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background: #3498db;
  height:500px;
}
.box-left{
  width:50%;
  float:left;
  height:500px;
  padding:50px;
}
.box-left h3{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.box-right{
  width:50%;
  float:right;
  height:500px;
}
.box-right img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-left">
      <h3>Head</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur quas a velit. Aut nihil, modi nobis corporis eveniet ratione aperiam repellat maiores corrupti quidem ipsam animi officiis, fugit quasi rem!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-right">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/S6PdtwP/69037904-2403297686584790-2753464427788369920-n.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="box-left">
      <h3>Head</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur quas a velit. Aut nihil, modi nobis corporis eveniet ratione aperiam repellat maiores corrupti quidem ipsam animi officiis, fugit quasi rem!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box-right">
      <img src="https://i.ibb.co/S6PdtwP/69037904-2403297686584790-2753464427788369920-n.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

live demo

[codepen live demo](https://codepen.io/cansalih/pen/NWKoeLo?editors=1100)